# Find a function with infinitely many local minimum points

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find a function with infinitely many local minimum points where x $\in$ [0,1] and f has only 1 root. No interval should exist where the function is constant.

Comment: f has only one solution?

Comment: The constant function has infinitely many minima in any interval.

Comment: Did you mean $f$ has only one zero?

Comment: If by one solution you mean one zero the how about
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0,\text{ if }x = 0 \\2+\sin\left(\frac1x\right),\text{ if } x \in \langle 0,1] \end{cases}$$

Comment: @JohnDouma 'No interval should exist where the function is constant'

Comment: @Jakobian Thank you. I did not see that.

Comment: @mechanodroid Nice, that works :). I knew it had to do with sin but I couldn't figure out how to make it infinitely cycle in that interval. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RubenShahnazaryan Even nicer, a continuous function: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0,\text{ if }x = 0 \\ x \sin\left(\frac1x\right),\text{ if } x \in \langle 0,1] \end{cases}$$

Comment: Nice :) thanks!

Comment: Oh but I don't think that works, it seems to have infinitely many roots right?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more extreme example than any thus far given.

Let $f(x)$ be [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). Note that $f:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow [0,1],$ and $f(x)$ has a strict local maximum at each rational number, and $f(x)$ is constant in no interval.

Let $g(x) = -f(x) + 2.$

Then $g(x)$ has a strict local minimum at each rational number and $g(x) > 0$ for each $x \in {\mathbb R}.$ Also, $g(x)$ is constant in no interval.

Now define $h:[0,1] \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ by $h(x) = g(x)$ if $0 < x \leq 1$ and $h(0) = 0.$

Then $h(x)$ has a strict local minimum at each rational number in its domain, and $h(x) = 0$ if and only if $x=0.$ Also, $h(x)$ is constant in no interval.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is find a function $g: t \rightarrow f(t)$ that has an infinite number of minima over an infinite interval, and then find a function $h$ that takes the unit interval to that interval. Then $g(h(x))$ has an infinite number of minima on the unit interval. It will be the open interval, but you don't say $f$ has to be continuous, so you can define $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ to be anything you want. For instance, take $g(t) = \sin(t)+2$ (you say $f$ can't have more than one "solution"; I assume you mean "root"). Then take $h(t) = \ln(x)$. Then $f(x)=\sin(\ln(x))+2$ when $x$ is in the open unit interval, and you can take $f(0)=0$.